# Centering the text in a cell in vertical distance

Tags: tables, ieeetran

Consider the following table definition.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title} 
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{my-label} shows
 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{The caption}
 \label{av-results}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|}
 \hline
     PDF \\
 \hline
    85.4 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it seems that the text inside cells are shifted up. I mean the top margin is less than bottom margin.

[image]

How can I place the text centered in the vertical distance?

Comment: Try adding a descender (letters like g or y) and you will find the spaces above and below are actually equal. You can also increase the row height if you wish by adding, e.g., `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a descender (letters like g or y) and you will find the spaces above and below are actually equal. You can also increase the row height if you wish by adding, e.g., `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`. For better looking tables, consider also using the `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title} 
\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{av-results} shows
 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{The caption}
 \label{av-results}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|}
 \hline
     PDFy  \\
 \hline
    85.4g \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table} 

 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
 \hline
     PDFy  \\
 \hline
    85.4g \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

The `cellspace` is here for that! It enables you to define *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C`, or any other letter you please, in case you also load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{my-label} shows
 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{The caption}
 \label{av-results}
 \begin{tabular}{|Sc|}
 \hline
     PDF \\
 \hline
    85.4 \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]